# Group by same-key columns with mix of binarization, sampling and mean aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe that has non-unique key-columns that I would like to **group by key** such that:

1. categorical columns with <= 30 unique values are turned into binarized set of columns (e.g pd.get_dummies) and averaged
2. categorical columns with > 30 unique values sample value randomly
3. numerical columns are averaged

for example

```
id,cat,cat2,num
0,0,1000,10
0,2,2000,20
1,0,3000,30
1,1,4000,40
1,3,4000,50
2,1,6000,60
2,3,6000,70
```

where `cat` is #1, `cat2` #2, `num` #3 (in list above) and `id` is a key.
Note that keys might be compound (>1), but in this example we have only 1.

It turns into

```
id,cat_0,cat_1,cat_2,cat_3,cat2,num
0,0.5,0.0,0.5,0.0,2000,15
1,0.33,0.33,0.0,0.33,4000,60
2,0.0,0.5,0.0,0.5,6000,65
```

Roughly I would write code smth like this (but I do not know how to do it actually in a right way)

```
def binarize_and_aggregate(df, col_name):
    cat_df = pd.get_dummies(df[[col_name]], drop_first=False)
    g = cat_df.groupby(keys)
    s = g.sum()
    sum = s.div(s.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
    return sum

def process_df(df):
    dic = {}
    for col in numeric_cols:
        dic[col] = 'mean'
    for col in categorical_cols_less_30:
        dic[col] = binarize_and_aggregate(df, col)
    for col in categorical_cols_more_30:
        dic[col] = lambda x: x.sample(1)

    result_df = df.groupby(keys).agg(dic)
    return result_df




final_result = process_df(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is one way

```
s1=pd.crosstab(df.id,df.cat,normalize='index').add_prefix('cat_')
s2=df.groupby('id').agg({'cat2':lambda x : x.sample(1),'num':'mean'})
pd.concat([s1,s2],axis=1)
Out[473]: 
       cat_0     cat_1  cat_2     cat_3  num  cat2
id                                                
0   0.500000  0.000000    0.5  0.000000   15  1000
1   0.333333  0.333333    0.0  0.333333   40  4000
2   0.000000  0.500000    0.0  0.500000   65  6000
```

---

Multiple key

```
s1=pd.crosstab([df.id,df.id2],df.cat,normalize='index').add_prefix('cat_')
s2=df.groupby(['id','id2']).agg({'cat2':lambda x : x.sample(1),'num':'mean'})
pd.concat([s1,s2],axis=1)
```

Comment: so here you reply on setting id as index. Is it possible to do it if our key is more than one column?

Comment: So should I do smth like this
df.index = [df.id,df.id2] beforehand? since it says normalize by index e.g normalize='index'?

Comment: @YohanRoth have you try , it just create the multiple index by corsstab